# is there any way to trim words in _e() function

Tags: php, wordpress

wp_trim_words is it works with _e() functions for translated text to limit the shown text ?

i have tried wordpress trim functions , and php trim wordpress length functions and did not works for me

```
<?php
                         $txt = _e(' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, distinctio, dolore! Amet atque, commodi consequuntur delectus deleniti eveniet expedita inventore laboriosam laborum, mollitia odit quia quidem recusandae repellendus suscipit tenetur.','domain');
                        echo wp_trim_words( $txt, 5 );
                        ?>
```

expecting the translated text appear with words limits of 20 words for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `_e( $text, $domain )` just print text and return null.
If you want to do something with txt you need to use function `__( $text, $domain )` that return edited txt.

Change your code like that:

```
<?php
$txt = __(' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, distinctio, dolore! Amet atque, commodi consequuntur delectus deleniti eveniet expedita inventore laboriosam laborum, mollitia odit quia quidem recusandae repellendus suscipit tenetur.','domain');
echo wp_trim_words( $txt, 5 );
?>
```